# How to add up to quarter hour hours

Tags: r, dataframe, time, transform

I have the dates in the data frame:

```
2021-05-04 01:00:00, 2021-05-04 01:00:00, 2021-05-04 01:00:00,
2021-05-04 01:00:00, 2021-05-05 02: 00:00, 2021-05-05 02:00:00,
2021-05-05 02:00:00, 2021-05-05 02:00:00, ...
```

I am trying to transform it into:

```
2021-05-04 01:00:00, 2021-05-04 01:15:00, 2021-05-04 01:30:00,
2021-05-04 01:45:00, 2021-05-05 02: 00:00, 2021-05-05 02:15:00,
2021-05-05 02:30:00, 2021-05-05 02:45:00, ...
```

I'm using code for this:

```
aaa <- aaa %>%
  tidyr::uncount(4) %>% 
  mutate(h_dec = datetime + (0:3)/4)
```

Unfortunately, the quarters of an hour are not added.
How to solve it?

Comment: Please paste your dates into the question using `dput(aaa)` so solutions can be tested.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your data is always start with the minute mark `00:00`

```r
library(dplyr)
aaa <- data.frame(date_time = as.POSIXct(c("2021-05-04 01:00:00", "2021-05-04 01:00:00",
  "2021-05-04 01:00:00", "2021-05-04 01:00:00", "2021-05-05 02:00:00",
  "2021-05-05 02:00:00", "2021-05-05 02:00:00", "2021-05-05 02:00:00")))

# assume that your data is always start with the mark 00:00
aaa %>%
  group_by(date_time) %>%
  mutate(date_time_update = seq(min(date_time), by = "15 min", length.out = n()))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#> # Groups:   date_time [2]
#>   date_time           date_time_update   
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1 2021-05-04 01:00:00 2021-05-04 01:00:00
#> 2 2021-05-04 01:00:00 2021-05-04 01:15:00
#> 3 2021-05-04 01:00:00 2021-05-04 01:30:00
#> 4 2021-05-04 01:00:00 2021-05-04 01:45:00
#> 5 2021-05-05 02:00:00 2021-05-05 02:00:00
#> 6 2021-05-05 02:00:00 2021-05-05 02:15:00
#> 7 2021-05-05 02:00:00 2021-05-05 02:30:00
#> 8 2021-05-05 02:00:00 2021-05-05 02:45:00
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I did this:
aaa <- aaa %>%
  tidyr::uncount(4) %>%
    mutate(datetime = seq(min(datetime), by = "15 min", length.out = n()))
It works. :)